# SspiPromptForCredentials Target Name

Tags: winapi, sspi

I've been developing an application that uses SSPI for Client / Server authentication. Everything works fine, but still one question remains.
The first argument of SspiPromptForCredentials is the target name... But what is it really used for?
I can literally put anything as a target name, my code will work. I don't even see it written anywhere (in the GUI).
Is it related to the authentication method? I use Negotiate.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be related to how the credentials are saved in the credential manager.

The [only `SspiPromptForCredentials` example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bits/example-using-sspi-authentication-encoding-with-bits) I can find on MSDN just uses a simple useless string (`"Target"`).

For `CredUIConfirmCredentials` MSDN says:

> Pointer to a null-terminated string that contains the name of the target for the credentials, typically a domain or server application name. 
>   This must be the same value passed as pszTargetName to CredUIPromptForCredentials or CredUICmdLinePromptForCredentials

`CredUICmdLinePromptForCredentials` has a similar parameter and for this MSDN says:

> A pointer to a null-terminated string that contains the name of the target for the credentials, typically a server name.
>
> **The pszTargetName parameter is used to identify the target information and is used to store and retrieve the credential**.
>
> ...
>
> Credentials are stored in the credential manager based on target name. Each target name is stored as generally as possible without colliding with credentials already stored in the credential manager. An important effect of storing credentials by target name is that a particular user can have only one credential per target stored in the credential manager.

These other CredUI functions are perhaps lower-level but I think the parameter usage is the same.

MSDN [says this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/microsoft-negotiate) about Negotiate:

> To allow Negotiate to select the Kerberos security provider, **the client application must provide a service principal name (SPN), a user principal name (UPN), or a NetBIOS account name as the target name**. Otherwise, Negotiate always selects the NTLM security provider.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a little more benign than you might think. SSPI supports arbitrary credential types, so the API needs to provide a way to prompt for credentials that a particular SSP understands without having to expose a 3rd party API. You can't launch a UI from within the SSP itself because it runs in LSA, so there's an implicit contract between the app builder and the SSP builder that if you need special credentials you're going to have to call `SspiPromptForCredentials`.

In some cases it's possible that SSP you're trying to use might require knowledge of the target to form the shape of the marshaled credential. Often times it doesn't.

Negotiate just happens to not require that information because the credentials you enter are not dependent on the target.